# quartic subfield of cyclotomic field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

I want to know which is the quartic subfield of the cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ where $p$ is an odd prime? it is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\varepsilon\sqrt{p}})$ where $\varepsilon$ is the fundamental unit of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt p)$? how to prove that?

Also, what are the sufields of a cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ where $n=2^a$?

Cordially

Comment: You'd better require $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ for the first question or there is no quartic subfield.  Concerning the second question, can you describe the subgroups of $(\mathbf Z/2^a\mathbf Z)^\times$?

Comment: Your guess $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{\varepsilon\sqrt{p}})$ is a quartic field that has a real embedding, so to even have a chance of working the maximal real subfield of ${\mathbf Q}(\zeta_p)$ needs to have degree divisible by $4$, so $(p-1)/2$ is divisible by $4$, which means $p \equiv 1 \bmod 8$. The first two such $p$ are $17$ and $41$, and for those two primes PARI says your guess works (it has an embedding into the $p$th cyclotomic field).

Comment: I think that $p$ must be $\equiv1\bmod8$, because in this case only $p$ is totally ramified in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\varepsilon\sqrt p})$.

Comment: If $p\equiv5\bmod8$ we are $p$ is totally ramified and $2$ is ramified in $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\varepsilon\sqrt p})$. thus $L$ is not a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$. how do you use Pari to see that L is a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$. best regards....

Comment: The PARI command nfisincl computes all embeddings of a number field generated by a root of one irreducible polynomial into a number field generated by a root of another irreducible polynomial. It returns the answer $0$ if there is no embedding at all.

Comment: After some numerical examples, I noticed the following: The cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ where $n=2^a;\ a>1$ has two quadratic subfields wich as $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1})$ and  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. And for $a>3$ $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\ \sqrt{-1})$ are the quartic subfields of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$.